# 'Access is denied' error when creating a new view in Superset

Tags: view, apache-superset

I've been trying to add an additional view extending `SimpleFormView` (in a similar way to how `CsvToDatabaseView` works).

I first started off by searched for all related `CsvToDatabaseView` code occurrences and created an equivalent of each for my new view. I am constantly getting an 'Access is denied' message (with a 302 redirect) whenever I try to open the this new url. (equivalent to `/csvtodatabaseview/form`).

Setting the new template path in `CsvToDatabaseView` does work however so problem seems to be with the form and it's url. Changing all occurrences of `CsvToDatabaseView` to `CvToDatabaseView` for testing purposes does not work either. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently after making the necessary code changes, one needs to run `superset init`
in order for this new connection to be persisted to the database.

Each exposed endpoint will get a permission entry added to the `ab_view_menu table`.